# $P(A|B_1 \cup B_2) \ge \min\{P(A|B_1),P(A|B_2)\}$ with $P(B_i)>0$ for $i=1,2.$

Tags: probability

I want to proof $P(A|B_1 \cup B_2) \ge \min\{P(A|B_1),P(A|B_2)\}$ with $P(B_i)>0$ for $i=1,2.$

What I tried:

$$P[A|B_1 \cup B_2]=\frac{P[A\cap(B_1 \cup B_2)]}{P[B_1 \cup B_2]}=\frac{P[(A \cap B_1) \cup (A \cap B_2)]}{P[B_1 \cup B_2]}$$

$$=\frac{P[A \cap B_1]+P[A \cap B_2]-P[A \cap B_1 \cap A \cap B_2]}{P[B1]+P[B2]-P[B_1 \cap B_2]}=\frac{P[A \cap B_1]+P[A \cap B_2]-P[A \cap B_1 \cap B_2]}{P[B1]+P[B2]-P[B_1 \cap B_2]}$$

But how do I continue?

Furthermore I need to show $P(A|B_i) \ge P(A) \Rightarrow P(A|B_1 \cup B_2)\ge P(A)$ for $i=1,2$

Comment: Firstly, which way is your inequality? Secondly, what I thought for $\ge$: If $P(A|B_1) \ge P(A|B_2)$, which we can assume by WOLOG, it would suffice to show that $P(A|B_1 \cup B_2) \ge P(A|B_2)$.

Comment: I edited it. It is $\ge$

Answer (score 1):

Both inequalities are false.

Flip a coin four times. Let $A = \{\text{two heads}\}$, $B_1 = \{\text{1st flip is }T\}$, $B_2 = \{\text{2nd flip is }H\}$. Then $P(A\mid B_i) = \frac38 =  P(A)$, but $P(A\mid B_1 \cup B_2) = \frac1{3} <\frac38$.

Comment: Can you explain why $P(A|B_1 \cup B_2)=\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: I can. But I also think that you can count it yourself.

Comment: I always end up with $\frac{1}{2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: $B_1\cup B_2 = \{TT**, TH**, HH**\}$. $A\cap(B_1\cup B_2)=\{TTHH,THHT,THTH,HHTT\}$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $4/16=1/4$ then?

Comment: No it shouldn't.